# qooxdoo modal window and opacity of parent widgets

Tags: javascript, window, modal-dialog, qooxdoo

I'm coding with qooxdoo. I have a TabView on the root. The tabview have a Dock layout.
I put a window with the modal property set as true.

When the window is opened, the widgets of parents get blocked. Nice. But that parents widgets dont' get opaque like on, for example, ExtJS.

Some way or idea for get opaque parent widget on open modal window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

qooxdoo uses a application blocker for modal windows which is invisible as default. But you can set a color / opacity for that blocker to a similar look. Check out the sample to see how it could be done in your application:

```
this.getRoot().setBlockerColor("black");
this.getRoot().setBlockerOpacity(0.2);
```

Here is also a working demo: http://tinyurl.com/oqfwmt4